# PHP PDO - How can I fix this issue?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm following the code from a book about PHP but I'm stuck in the following problem: It display my posts from my database but when I click on the "Read more" link it tells me it couldn't find the URL. The Following is the code

Any suggestions about what is wrong would be much appreciate.

**posts.php**

```
<?php
Class Posts {
    public $db = '';
    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testposts", "username", "password");
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->index(); 

    }

    public function index(){
        $id = 0;
        $posts = array();
        $template = '';
        if (!empty($_GET['id'])){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        }

        try {
            if (!empty($id)){
                $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
                $params = array($id);
                $template = 'single-post.php';
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
                $params = array();
                $template = 'list-posts.php';
            }
            $query->execute($params);
            for ($i = 0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++) {
                $posts[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'content' => $row['content']);
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
        $db = null;
        require_once($template);
    }
}

$posts = new Posts();

?>
```

**list-posts.php**

```
 <h1>List of Blog Posts</h1>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <h3>Post # <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?></h3>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['content']); ?>
        <a href="http://localhost/other/posts.php?id=<?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?>">Read More</a>
        <hr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**single-post.php**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <h1>Post #<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['content']); ?>
    <a href="http://localhost/other/posts.php">Back to Post List</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You're hard-coding the URL string to your localhost - is the file in the location specified? `http://localhost/other/posts.php` You should likely use relative rather than absolute paths.

Comment: You've hard-coded a URL on `http://localhost` which will only work on the machin on which the server is running. Remove that and use relative URLs. You should check that the id in the URL is actually valid too,

Comment: I believe so, I mean, when I run .../other/posts.php it display a list of all my posts (Id + content). However, when I click on read more it gives me the "URL not found" message. When I click on the my first post "Read more" link (id=1), this is the URL that my browser show me: http://localhost/other/posts.php? id=1. 

I'm not complete sure what you mean by relative/absolute paths. Bare with me please. (I'll  google it)

Comment: What is the full URL that you use when looking at your initial list?

Comment: Hobo Sapiens, I will figure out how to use relative URLs. Thanks for your comment. 


rjdown, it is http://localhost/other/posts

Comment: Ah then you just need to remove the .php from the other URLs (but also do the thing hobo said! - so just `/other/posts?id=xxx`)